# Iterating over a list of mongo DB collections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to iterate over a list of collections and remove any document with the _id of '1236' in the cheese db. When running the code below, nothing gets deleted. The logic does, however, work when explicitly use a collection's name self.db.chips.remove({"_id":_id})). What am i doing wrong?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient



class dump:

    def __init__(self,MONGODB_HOST,MONGODB_PORT,DBS_NAME):
        self.client = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
        self.db = self.client[DBS_NAME]


    def delete_account(self,_id):
        names = self.db.collection_names()
        for name in names:
            self.db.name.remove({"_id":_id})

db1 = dump('localhost',27017,'cheese')

print db1.delete_account('1236')
```

Comment: Is cheese a db or a collection?

Comment: sorry, i made an error. Cheese is a db. chips is one of the collections within db.

Comment: what is `db.collect`?

Comment: Where have you declared your collection name in your code? I dont see one.

Comment: names = a list of collections. So, names = [chips, cookies, cake]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems there:

- In your for loop name is string so `self.db.name.remove({"_id":_id})` will result in attribute error.
- You can't delete from `system` namespace so you need to filter out collection with name starts with **`system.`** note the dot.

  ```
  def delete_account(self,_id):
      names = [collection for collection in  self.db.collection_names() if not collection.startswith('system.')]
      for name in names:
          self.db[name].remove({'_id': _id})
  ```